# qemu-system-arm and lm3s6965evb / Cortex M3 ... need more ram

Tags: qemu

I'm successfully compiling my unit-test with arm-eabi-none-gcc and running them in qemu-system-arm with the machine lm3s6965evb.... But for some of the unit-tests I need more than the 64k of RAM that the lm3s6965evb mcu/machine has.

The IAR simulator apparently has no hard limit in the 'machine', so I just made a phony linkerfile that allows the unittest-program to use e.g. 512k RAM. This works (surprisingly) fine , but qemu doesn't play like that (hangs the moment I change the RAM section in the linkerfile). So I need another machine...

But thinking about it: I think I just need something that executes ARMv7 thumb(2?) code, like the CortexM3. It could also be Cortex-M33 which is a ARMv8 ...
I don't care about Hardware-registers or interrupts etc. I do need, however, printf() to work via semihosting or other means (uart etc), to printout unittest status (success/failures)

What are my best candidates,

- modify the lm3s6965evb somehow?
- taking an A7?
- taking some of the ARM vhdl/fpga machines? (msp2.. musca ...) ?
- (The 'virt' machine does not support cortex-m3/m4, according to error message)

?

Thanks

/T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It turns out, that I misread the "mps2-an385" documentation & tutorials, - it wasn't complicated at all.)

It works if I just use the "mps2-an385" machine and modify the linkerfile to use more flash and ram. Currently i beefed it up to 4x ram and flash which is enough currently. (Haven't found out what the exact limits are.)

Still, I would like to hear if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

QEMU's lm3s6965evb model follows the real hardware, which does not have much RAM. If you want more RAM and you don't specifically want to have a model of those Stellaris boards, pick a board model type which has more RAM. If you need to use an M-profile core, try one of the MPS2 boards. If you are happy with an A-profile core, then the "virt" board with a Cortex-A15 may be a good choice.